# How to use user defined types in a dimension in oracle 11g r2

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, data-warehouse

I'm implementing a dwh in oracle. I have 2 user defined types. And there are two nested table type which are built via these types. But I want to use them in dimension. There is a problem. There are no selection in datatype tab how can I fix this problem. I have imported all types from db.

Comment: What does "datatype tab" mean?  Are you using some sort of GUI?  If so, what GUI?

Comment: right click to dimension> New dimension > names ans data types (here is data type tab) > levels

Comment: "right click" implies that you are using some sort of GUI.  If so, what GUI?

Comment: Im using oracle Warehouse builder(design center)